# jQuery UI Datepicker - how to select year

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

Is there any way to allow the user to select the year on the datepicker? In its default state, one has to leaf through the months to get to a different year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

See this [example](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year)